# R read excel file numeric precision problem

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I have a number in an excel file that is equal to `-29998,1500000003`

[image: excelfile]

When I try to open it in R I get

```
> library(openxlsx)
> posotest <- as.character(read.xlsx("sofile.xlsx"))
> posotest
[1] "-29998.1500000004"
```

Any help? Desired result: `-29998,1500000003`

---

**EDIT:** with `options(digits=13)` I get `-29998.150000000373` which could explain why the rounding is done, however even with `options(digits=13)` I get

```
> as.character(posotest)
[1] "-29998.1500000004"
```

Do you have any function that would allow me to get the full number in characters?

---

**EDIT2** `format` does this but it adds artificial noise at the end.

```
x <- -29998.150000000373
format(x,digits=22)
[1] "-29998.15000000037252903"
```

How can I know how many digits to use in `format` since `nchar` will give me a wrong value?

The file is [here](https://ufile.io/aut9h)

Comment: It reads in fine for me if I don't convert it to character. Once I force R to show all the digits, the value is -29998.150000000373. Which of course suggests that Excel is lying to you more than R is.

Comment: try `options(digits=13)`

Comment: Then why doesn't `as.character` show all digits? see question edits

Comment: Your question about `as.character` is answered in the documentation: "as.character represents real and complex numbers to 15 significant digits (technically the compiler's setting of the ISO C constant DBL_DIG, which will be 15 on machines supporting IEC60559 arithmetic according to the C99 standard). This ensures that all the digits in the result will be reliable (and not the result of representation error), but does mean that conversion to character and back to numeric may change the number. If you want to convert numbers to character with the maximum possible precision, use format."

Comment: @joran, `format` seems to add noise. How can I know in advance how many digits to use in `format` since `nchar` will give me a wrong value?

Comment: @gpier "How can I know in advance how many digits are correct and display those only?" As a general matter, that is an incredibly complex question. How many digits are "reliable" will depend on all sorts of things, like what values were used as inputs and the specific sequence of arithmetic steps that led to the result. Unless you're in a _highly_ specialized field, most people simply rely on software defaults, like R's choice to show only -29998.15, and only more when forced to.

Comment: For instance, unless you know enough about floating point arithmetic to actually start second guessing compiler standards, a good rule of thumb might be to follow R's documentation in ?`as.character` and only rely on the first 15 digits.

Comment: @joran, I am obliged to ask this, working in finance, even slight rate differences applied to large sums can cause significant errors. The correct number *is* there, R does tell me it is `-29998.150000000373` and I need to be able to save *exactly* that in excel, hence the need to convert to chars

Comment: You might want to start looking into arbitrary precision arithmetic packages in R, then. Or you can use `format` but you'd have to know the number of digits you want in advance.

Comment: `format` adds noise, which is not acceptable. Any other ? - by the way I tried `Rmpfr` which doesn't seem to have a way to translate to chars

Comment: `format` doesn't "add noise", it just shows whatever numerical representation the computer has. You can get the answer you want with `format` if you supply the correct number of digits.

Comment: Alternatively, maybe you'd prefer the **readxl** package which allows you to read the column specifically as character, which yields the answer you want.

Comment: Many thanks... this is what I needed. moreover, `nchar` gives the correct number using this method

Answer (score 3):

You can get a string with up to 22 digits of precision via `format()`:

```
x <- -29998.150000000373
format(x,digits=22)
[1] "-29998.15000000037252903"
```

Of course, this will show you all sorts of ugliness related to trying to represent a decimal number in a binary representation with finite precision ...

Comment: Ok so I am *not* crazy. Are you sure that the `373` part is correct and not the `37252903`? How can I know in advance how many digits are correct and display those only?